# How to keep user logged in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hello I am trying to store keep user logged in in a xamarin app.

The official tutorials talk about how to log in but not how to keep user logged in.
[Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users)
[xamarin Tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/azure/)

My problem is that the Login method must be run every time the app is re launched which brings up a blank screen for a while before it comes off.

Login Method

```
async void Login()
        {
            if(App.Authenticator != null && authenticated == false)
            {
                authenticated = await App.Authenticator.Authenticate();
            }
        }
```

Authenticate method

```
public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
        {
            var success = false;
            var message = string.Empty;

            try
            {

                    //Sign in with Active Directory Service
                user = await ShopItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(this,
                    MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory);



                if (user != null)
                {
                    message = string.Format("You are now signed in as {0}", user.UserId);
                    success = true;
                    //store token
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message = ex.Message;
            }

            //Display the success or failure message
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.SetMessage(message);
            builder.SetTitle("Sign-in Result");
            builder.Create().Show();

            return success;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting some kind of login cookie?

Comment: I would but i really have no clue how.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/System.Web.HttpRequest.Cookies/

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use [xamarin settings plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings/), follow the below steps.

1. Install settings plugin.
2. Add Settings class.

```
    public static class SettingsHelper
    {

        private static ISettings AppSettings
        {
            get
            {
                return CrossSettings.Current;
            }
        }

        #region Setting Constants

        private const string LoginKey = "login_key";
        private static readonly string SettingsDefault = string.Empty;

        #endregion


        public static string GeneralSettings
        {
            get
            {
                return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(LoginKey, SettingsDefault);
            }
            set
            {
                AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(LoginKey, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Inside login method set value to GeneralSettings and next time app opening check for the general settings value and assign navigation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about Xamrin but in native android we use `SharedPreferences` to save login state. SharedPreferences are used in android to store some data presistently(i.e. after closing of application, it will persist). We can put a boolean to detect if the user is successfully loggedin on the next launch.

The Xamarin.Android equivalent of `SharedPreferences` is an interface called `ISharedPreferences`.

Use it in the same way, and you will be able to easily port Android code across.

---

For example, to save a true/false `bool` using some `Context` you can do the following:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();
editor.PutBoolean ("key_login_successfully", true);
// editor.Commit();    // applies changes synchronously on older APIs
editor.Apply();        // applies changes asynchronously on newer APIs
```

Access saved values using:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
mBool = prefs.GetBoolean ("key_login_successfully", <default value>);
```

---

From this sample, you can see that once you know the correct C# interface to use, the rest is easy. There are many Android java examples on how to use `SharedPreferences` for more complex situations, and these can be ported very easily using `ISharedPreferences`.

For more information, read this thread:

- [Android Shared Preference on Xamarin forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4758/android-shared-preference)

Comment: That is what I intend to do next. The problem is that the user isn't logged in when the app relaunches. The Azure mobile app api is not accessible to the application until I re-run the login method.

Comment: I am not sure about Azure mobile app api. But to coverup  the white screen you can try setting some splash screen background and try showing some progressbar so that user gets to know that something is going on.

Comment: I finally found a solution, which is related to what you mentioned. But because of of xamarin and azure specifc features it was a rather involved process. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

So [This tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/personalized-experiences-with-azure-mobile-apps-authentication/) has the information in it. It is a bit involved.

This code stores the key. Which another user did indeed mention. Although this is cross platform.
    public static class Settings
    {
        private static ISettings AppSettings => CrossSettings.Current;

```
    const string UserIdKey = "userid";
    static readonly string UserIdDefault = string.Empty;

    const string AuthTokenKey = "authtoken";
    static readonly string AuthTokenDefault = string.Empty;

    public static string AuthToken
    {
        get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault<string>(AuthTokenKey, AuthTokenDefault); }
        set  { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue<string>(AuthTokenKey, value); }
    }

    public static string UserId
    {
        get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault<string>(UserIdKey, UserIdDefault);  }
        set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue<string>(UserIdKey, value); }
    }

    public static bool IsLoggedIn => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserId); 
}
```

However this Auth handler when passed with the client constructor will ensure that the stored credentials will be used if any are saved.

```
    class AuthHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public IMobileServiceClient Client { get; set; }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (this.Client == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Make sure to set the 'Client' property in this handler before using it.");
        }

        // Cloning the request, in case we need to send it again
        var clonedRequest = await CloneRequest(request);
        var response = await base.SendAsync(clonedRequest, cancellationToken);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            // Oh no! user is not logged in - we got a 401
            // Log them in, this time hardcoded with MicrosoftAccount but you would
            // trigger the login presentation in your application
            try
            {
                var user = await this.Client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, null);
                // we're now logged in again.

                // Clone the request
                clonedRequest = await CloneRequest(request);


                Settings.UserId = user.UserId;
                Settings.AuthToken = user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken;

                clonedRequest.Headers.Remove("X-ZUMO-AUTH");
                // Set the authentication header
                clonedRequest.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);

                // Resend the request
                response = await base.SendAsync(clonedRequest, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                // user cancelled auth, so let’s return the original response
                return response;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    private async Task<HttpRequestMessage> CloneRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var result = new HttpRequestMessage(request.Method, request.RequestUri);
        foreach (var header in request.Headers)
        {
            result.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        if (request.Content != null && request.Content.Headers.ContentType != null)
        {
            var requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var mediaType = request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
            result.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType);
            foreach (var header in request.Content.Headers)
            {
                if (!header.Key.Equals("Content-Type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    result.Content.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }


   }
    }

    return result;
}
}
```